# Bash: Reuse printf variables in output

Tags: bash, variables, printf

Is it possible to use the variables passed to `printf` more than once in the formatting?

For example, with this line:

```
printf 'Hi %s, welcome to %s. %s is a great place to work. Thanks %s.' "John" "The Icecream Factory"
```

How can I "reuse" the first and second variables in `printf`?

I'm thinking something like:

```
printf 'Hi %s[1], welcome to %s[2]. %s[1] is a great place to work. Thanks %s[2].' "John" "The Icecream Factory"
```

... but obviously that's not it.

#### Desired output

```
Hi John, welcome to The Icecream Factory. The Icecream Factory is a great place to work. Thanks John.
```

#### Actual output

```
Hi John, welcome to The Icecream Factory.  is a great place to work. Thanks .
```

Working environment is `bash` in Ubuntu 20.

Comment: I don't believe `printf` format characters support that. What's the reason you have to use `%s`? It's easier to define variables, which can be used multiple times in a String, e.g. `n="John"; f="The Icecream Factory"; printf "Hi $n, welcome to $f. $f is a great place to work. Thanks $n."`

Comment: Yes, that works fine, but I've been told it's bad practice to use variables in the `printf` format string: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2059

Comment: There are pitfalls to be aware of but it's not that serious. You can also use `echo` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't think it's possible using either the built-in `bash` implementation of `printf` or the freestanding GNU `printf(1)` program, if you can target `zsh` instead, its version of `printf` supports POSIX-style `printf(3)` argument indexing:

> Normally, conversion specifications are applied to each argument in order but they can explicitly specify the `n`th argument is to be used by replacing `%` by `%n$` and `*` by `*n$`. It is recommended that you do not mix references of this explicit style with the normal style and the handling of such mixed styles may be subject to future change.

```sh
$ printf 'Hi %1$s, welcome to %2$s. %2$s is a great place to work. Thanks %1$s.\n' "John" "The Icecream Factory"
Hi John, welcome to The Icecream Factory. The Icecream Factory is a great place to work. Thanks John.
```

Comment: If this is ever added to `bash`, it would almost certainly use the same syntax, fwiw.